# Oracle SQL spool

Tags: oracle, split, spool

I don't know if this is achievable via SQL in Oracle

I have table with 114000 plus records having Customer codes and sales person code.

Now I need to spool this in 10 or 11  separate files so each file contain 1/10 or less records to be grouped on sp code

Able to get first 14000 rec

with tt as (select br,count(*) cc,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(*) )rn  from temp2  group by (br) order by cc)

SELECT cc,count(cc)
FROM
(
SELECT br,  cc,
(
SELECT SUM(cc)
FROM tt
WHERE rn <= t.rn  ) total
FROM tt t order by cc
) q
WHERE total <= (select count(*)/10 from temp2) group by cc order by cc

Now how to loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle sqlplus spool to multiple files by row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752289/oracle-sqlplus-spool-to-multiple-files-by-row-number)

Comment: I am able to make upto

Comment: Row number or any other field from `select` list really does not matter. Because a short answer is: no, it is not possible.